# Swapping elements in jquery when dropped on a area?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an IMG tag which needs to be replaced by an Input element like text box when dropped on a area. I am able to clone, drag and drop, by add i am able to a add a input box, but the image that i cloned is also coming there. How can i hide/remove the image?

here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#txtInpt" ).draggable({  
    appendTo: "body",  
            helper: "clone"
    });     
$( "#phone" ).droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
              ui.draggable.clone().add('<input type="text">').appendTo(this);
           }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-drag-and-drop-replace-the-position/) link where the same question is discussed and resolved with sample. And obviously more faq questions with answers are avail to know more.